# Configuring Windows Workstations to use their TPM in Bit Locker for all drives?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-10, bitlocker, tpm

I have a bunch of AD-integrated workstations that will need to use BitLocker.  They all have TPM 2.0 installed, and my overall goal is to get BitLocker set up and using the TPM for both the OS drive and a fixed data SSD we have in these machines.

To my understanding, you can't turn on BitLocker within a GPO itself, but only configure a bunch of parameters - this is OK as there's only about 20 machines.  Without setting anything up, it *appears* as if Windows 10 will use it for the OS drive - I can walk through the wizard, set a recovery key location, etc. without it automatically trying to prompt me for a password or whatever.  To my understanding if I did want to set a pin or password, that could be set in GPO, but that is not the default.

Over on the fixed data drive, however, no such luck - before I get anywhere, it automatically requires me to set either a password *or* use a smart card.  Neither of these are desirable.

Is there a way to set up a Windows machine to want to use the TPM, and thus never ask for passwords or cards or whatever, when encrypting it in BitLocker?  My assumption was that setting "Configure use of hardware-based encryption for fixed data drives" might be the thing I'd want to look at, enabling it and *unchecking* the "Use software-based" setting completely, but my research online is inconclusive.

How does one go about accomplishing this, or can it not be done?

Comment: `Is there a way to set up a Windows machine to want to use the TPM` 

BitLocker saves the auto unlock key in the registry on operating system partition. 


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/enable-bitlockerautounlock

Comment: Greg, thanks for the lead - so if I am understanding this correctly, I should enable BitLocker on the OS drive en masse, then distribute the commend "Enable-BitLockerAutoUnlock -MountPoint "E:"" in some way to the assets, and then try to do the Data volume?